# How do I move (not copy) a file/folder from my hard drive to a flash drive?

Tags: finder, mojave

I have a few movie files I want to move to a flash drive. I don't want the file copied. Once they are moved to the flash drive, I don't want the original to remain on my hard drive.

If I do a simple drag and drop in Finder from one drive to another, it copies the files.

When I right click on the movie files I do not get an option to simply move.

I'm trying to move from `_temp` to `_M`.

[image]

The menu I get when I right click looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key while dragging from the source location to the destination location.

Doing this will perform a **move** and not a **copy**.

If you rather prefer to use keyboard shortcuts, simply copy file(s)/folder(s) normally using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and perform a move operation using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> at the destination location. Skipping <kbd>Option</kbd> will perform a copy-paste.

[Here's a quick list of tips](https://gizmodo.com/20-tips-and-tricks-for-managing-files-on-macos-1828411361) for managing files in macOS.

Comment: cmd + C and then option + cmd + v also do the trick

Comment: Thanks @EddGrowl.  Feel free to edit my answer to add that info!

Comment: `command - drag`.  Thank you. Surprised Apple does not provide a cheat sheet somewhere online.

Comment: Actually, they post many different user tutorials for how to use the system.  [Here's one of them](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) on keyboard shortcuts.  There's so many things you can do it will make your head spin!  If this answer works for you, please be sure to accept it in order to help others.

Comment: Can you please explain how/why on my Macbook Pro "move vs. copy" is the default behavior? On my Mac Pro I know that prior to my upgrading to Mojave I could also have "move vs. copy" as my default Desktop behavior as well.  Is there any kind of Terminal Command that can make it default to "move"? (Without having to use Command key)

Comment: I have no idea why it's different on your machine. To avoid cluttering this question, I would recommend [asking a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to do what you want.

Comment: For the opposite problem: `Option`-drag will **copy** (not move) a file. This is helpful dragging within the same drive.